# How do you make a object instance as function 's default argument?

Tags: php

I'm trying to have a default argument for my function. So for example you can normally always do something like.

```
function foo ($var = 'blah')
{
    return $var;
}
```

but I encounter a parse error that says unexpected T_VARIABLE when I try something a little more complex.

```
function foo ($var = $this->string)
{
    return $var;
}
```

How would you use the instance of an object as a default argument. Thanks!

Comment: You could use `$var = null` and then check to see if it's null.

Comment: Default parameters should be constant expressions, not variables, members of a class or calls to a function.

Answer (score 2):

```
function foo ($var = null)
{
    return ($var === null) ? $this->string : $var;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate an object from the default function argument value.

You could test for `$null` and then instantiate it in the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.  Function parameters can only be initialized to constant values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. Default values can only be constants.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

"The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call."